# When is ㄹ pronounced as L and when as R?

Tags: pronunciation

How do I know when to know the L pronunciation or the R pronunciation for ㄹ ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question is hard to answer directly, because it's never *really* the same as either an L **or** an R.

The base pronunciation of ㄹ in the initial position (such as in 라) is a "Flap R" or [Alveolar Lateral Flap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental,_alveolar_and_postalveolar_lateral_flaps).

In the 받침 it is similar to a light L, or something sort of between an L and an R. When this is followed immediately by another ㄹ, the light-L sound is elongated.

Comment: I would add that double-ㄹ sound most like L, for example 빨리. Is it right?

Comment: @파울울 That falls into the second situation, it is an elongation of the Light-L sound. I've edited the answer to be more detailed for that case.